# PHP preg_match: Extract full javascript function based on indent

Tags: php, pcre

I have an input like this

```
var example = ...

var foobar = function() {
    var barfoo = function() {

    }
}


var something = ...
```

I want to extract the function foobar.

How can I extract the text from `var foobar` until a closing bracket which is at the first indentation level?

```
preg_match('#var foobar =.*^}/#ms', $this->body, $matches);
```

Does not give any matches.

Comment: regexps not for parsing..

Answer (score -1):

This returns what you want:

```
preg_match('#var foobar =.*}#ms', $this->body, $matches);
```

But it will not work if you fill the dots at the end with more functions.

> Regular expressions are the wrong tool for the job because you are
>   dealing with nested structures, i.e. recursion.

[Regular Expression to match outer brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets)

Comment: I thought so. That's why I added the quote and the link. You need a JavaScript Parser. Maybe you can use this: https://github.com/kbjr/UglifyJS.php/blob/master/javascript-parser.php